# How to use COMMON API in a tooltip?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

according to the docs:

https://ng.ant.design/components/tooltip/en#common-api

There are three methods, hide, show and updatePosition.
How do i use them? i tried to ViewChild the component with the nz-tooltip, and applying the .hide() on that, but no luck. How can i target an specific nz-tooltip?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case the common API is exposed by the tooltip directive. You can grab it by using a template variable referencing the directive:

```
#tooltip="nzTooltip"
```

this way you can use "tooltip" to call the API method you desire, either in the template directly

```
<button (click)="tooltip.show()">Show</button>
```

or recalling the template variable in the component's typescript using viewChild.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpp37y